# Two different versions of VIM

Tags: vim, vi

When I install just about any distribution of linux it's accompanied with an unorthodox version of `vi`. I most recently dealt with this on Ubuntu 14.04. I can `vi` a file but a number of the "hot" keys are different. I have to reinstall `vim` via `$ sudo apt-get install vim` and after that everything works fine.

Before using `apt-get` is it even `vim` that I'm using? Why does this happen? Are there instructions for this "basic" version of `vim`?

** EDIT **

If I `$ vi` I see a short writeup which states "version 7.4.52". Then I upgraded and it was still at the same version however I noticed that the writeup is a bit different. There's a couple commands missing after the upgrade and I believe one of them was to switch a command mode. Maybe that command mode is enabled by default in this other version?

Comment: Have you tried "man vi"? Many variants of vi exist. Vim is the most advanced and largest of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the whims of the vendor; some (e.g. Redhat) include a "minimal vim" that behaves in a compatible fashion to `vi`, to be specific "mostly like Vi" per the `-C` option docs in the `vim` manual. Others could install [`nvi`](https://sites.google.com/a/bostic.com/keithbostic/vi/) (this is what OpenBSD ships with) or [`ex-vi`](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net) (likely the most orthodox version, and thus least likely to be installed), though I suspect most will install a vim-that-behaves-mostly-like-vi, in which case you'll want to peruse the vim-in-compatible-mode docs.